# Extract the 1st occurrence of a string based on a keyword

Tags: regex

I want to capture all ASCII string within the parentheses before the keyword "end". However, I am only interested in capturing the 1st matching group.

How do I ignore the 2nd matching group?

This is the sample regex which I wrote: `\((.+?)\) end`

And this is the sample string which I used: `"There are some other sentences before (some otherwords which I am not interested in) all these.This is a sample string (something which I am interested in) end. This is another repeated string (with some otherwords) end."`

I am only interested to obtain the output "somethings which I am interested in" which is in between the parentheses.

Comment: `^(?:[^(]+)\((.+?)\)`

Comment: @splash58 sometimes, it may not be at the start of the string.

Comment: why not just remove the global flag. Can you share the code that you are using. like this https://regex101.com/r/Z5ohnY/1

Comment: It skip not parentheses chars from the start of a string

Comment: I am only interested to extract the words in the parentheses if the word after the parentheses is "end". i.e. This is a sentence (Words which I am interested in) end.

Comment: If there are 2 keyword "end", how do I get the regex to match the 1st matching group?

Comment: What do you mean by global flag? I did not specify /g

Comment: i misread in that case

Comment: @Gurman, https://regex101.com/r/qrh4zL/5, if there are parentheses within the parentheses, we will have issues with the regex. I am not sure if we can even extract such keywords.

Comment: Did my answer solve your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me answer to your original question first.

> I want to capture all ASCII string within the parentheses before the
>   keyword "end". However, I am only interested in capturing the 1st
>   matching group.
>
> How do I ignore the 2nd matching group?

**Input:**

```
There are some other sentences before (some otherwords which I am not interested in) all these.This is a sample string (something which I am interested in) end. This is another repeated string (with some otherwords) end.
```

**Expected capture:**

```
somethings which I am interested in
```

**Regex to use:**

```
^(?<!\) end).*?\(([^()]+?)\) end
```

**Demo:** https://regex101.com/r/dVo9Zi/1

**Additional notes:**

- In one of your comments you said:

> if there are parentheses within the parentheses, we will have issues
>   with the regex. I am not sure if we can even extract such keywords.

If you need to analyze nested structures, you have to forget about regex and for a parser, as explained here: [Can regular expressions be used to match nested patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns)

- If you really mean all **ASCII** strings in your question, then you will have to adapt `[^()]` in the regex and replace it by the successive intervals in hexadecimal of all ASCII characters and you will have to explicitly exclude `(` and `)`. This gives you the following character class: `[\x00-\x27\x2A-\x7F]`. **Reference**: http://www.asciitable.com/, **demo:** https://regex101.com/r/dVo9Zi/2